# how to concatenate more than two columns in plsql developer?

Tags: sql, oracle

when I run the below query

```
select concat(column1,column2,column3)  as concatcolumn from table
```

I get an error "`ORA-00909:INVALID NUMBER OF ARGUMENTS`"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concat only takes two arguments.
See: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions026.htm

Use the concatenation operator:

```
select column1 || column2 || column3 ...
```

Answer (score -4):

```
select ([column1]+','+[column2]+','+[column3]) as concatcolumn from table
```

Try above the query.it may changes on different type of column data type.

Comment: Oracle uses `||` as the string concatenation operator, not `+`; and doesn't enclose column names in square brackets. The OP also hasn't asked for commas between the values.